# compress multiple files at once but don't put them all into one file?

Tags: compression

I want to compress multiple files at once (one command) but I don't want to put them into same directory or same file. How'd I do it?

Comment: If you consider a loop in one line as one command, you can loop over the to-be-compressed files, and in the loop compress each file individually. Otherwise, it depends on the compression-tool you're using, if it allows compressing multiple files individually. Tha manpage for that tool might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One tool to compress a file is `gzip`. To compress lots of files you can check the documentation, `man gzip`, where it writes

> **SYNOPSIS**
> `gzip [ -acdfhklLnNrtvV19 ] [-S suffix] [ name ...  ]`
>
> **DESCRIPTION**
> Gzip  reduces  the  size  of the named files […]. Whenever possible, each file is replaced by one with the extension `.gz`, while keeping the same ownership modes, access and modification times.

The last part of the synopsis, `[ name … ]` shows that it can take *zero or more* file names. (See `man man` for an explanation of the meta characters used in the Synopsis.) So if the files to compress are `wheat`, `oats`, and `barley` you could do this

```
gzip wheat oats barley
```

producing three separate compressed files, `wheat.gz`, `oats.gz`, and `barley.gz`.

Of course you can also use a wildcard, which the shell will attempt to match and expand to a list of files.